# How to import terminal pip installed tensorflow into pycharm

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, pycharm

The solution I found is to install tensorflow packages in pycharm's interpreter in each different new project. The file is incredibily huge and I think is a waste of space. Is there any solution to import terminal installed tensorflow to pycharm ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean that you want to reuse a virtual Python environment in PyCharm where TensorFlow is installed.

For example you have a conda environment created:

`conda create -n tensorflow -py 3.7.5`

`conda activate tensorflow`

`pip install tensorflow`

And you create a new project in PyCharm. You can select an existing interpreter. Select the conda environment called tensorflow. Et voila.

If this is not the answer you needed, please give a more elaborate explanation of your question.

Comment: What if I already installed tensorflow throught my window command prompt using pip. Pycharm still doesnt seem to recognized it.

Comment: If you are using linux/mac you could run the command `which python` to locate the Python environment you are using. Then navigate to that specific location when creating a project in PyCharm.